# Clubbing object array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, generics

Is there any efficient way to club object arrays? I have a model `[sales]`, which has `saleAmount, soldBy`. There could be multiple items sold by different customers. So what I wanted is, if items sold by, say, ABC then I wanted to sum the saleAmount sold by ABC. An example is given below.

```
class Sale  {

    var soldBy : String = "" 
    var saleAmount : Double = 0.00
}
var sales : [sale] = [sale]()

sales array contains:
[
["ABC", 1200.34],
["ABC", 999.34],
["ABC", 3499.99],
["DEF", 333.32],
["DEF", 778.12]
]

Expected output :
[["ABC", 5699.67],
["DEF" , 1111.44]]
```

Comment: Is `sale` a struct? If so, do provide its declaration in your question

Comment: sale is a class. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sequence of key/value pairs from the sales, and
use [`Dictionary(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995340-init)
to create a dictionary with the unique keys and the sums of the
corresponding values:

```
struct Sale  {
    let soldBy: String
    let saleAmount: Double
}

let sales = [
    Sale(soldBy: "ABC", saleAmount: 1200.34),
    Sale(soldBy: "ABC", saleAmount: 999.34),
    Sale(soldBy: "ABC", saleAmount: 3499.99),
    Sale(soldBy: "DEF", saleAmount: 333.32),
    Sale(soldBy: "DEF", saleAmount: 778.12),
]

let sums = Dictionary(sales.map { ($0.soldBy, $0.saleAmount) },
                      uniquingKeysWith: { $0 + $1 })

print(sums)
// ["ABC": 5699.67, "DEF": 1111.44]
```

Then you can create an array of sales from the dictionary:

```
let sumSales = sums.map { Sale(soldBy: $0.key, saleAmount: $0.value) }

print(sumSales)
// [Sale(soldBy: "ABC", saleAmount: 5699.67), Sale(soldBy: "DEF", saleAmount: 1111.44)]
```

For demonstration purposes I assume that `Sale` is a *struct.*

Comment: Martin - I have asked one more question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373155/efficient-and-clean-way-of-populating-array-dictionary-in-tableview.

Answer (score 2):

Having:

```
struct Sales {
    let name: String
    let amount: Float

    init(name: String, amount: Float) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

I'll add:

```
extension Sales {
    init(withSales initialSales: Sales, otherSale: Sales) {
        self.init(name: initialSales.name, amount: initialSales.amount + otherSale.amount)
    }
}
```

I'll use `reduce(into:_:)`:

```
let sales: [Sales] = [Sales(name: "ABC", amount: 1200.34),
                      Sales(name: "ABC", amount: 999.34),
                      Sales(name: "ABC", amount: 3499.99),
                      Sales(name: "DEF", amount: 333.32),
                      Sales(name: "DEF", amount: 778.12)]

let reducedSale = sales.reduce(into: [Sales]()) { (currentResult, current) in
    if let existingSalesIndex = currentResult.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == current.name }) {
        let existingSale = currentResult[existingSalesIndex]
        currentResult[existingSalesIndex] = Sales(withSales: existingSale, otherSale: current)

    } else {
        currentResult.append(current)
    }
}

print("reducedSales: \(reducedSales: [AppName.Sales(name: "ABC", amount: 5699.67), AppName.Sales(name: "DEF", amount: 1111.44)])
```

Since you use a class, you could avoid the convenience init, and just add the amount.

Comment: Thanks. I used the above code and I'm getting error in if let existingSalesIndex = currentResult.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == current.name }) --> Value of type '[Sales]' has no member 'firstIndex'

Comment: You don't use Swift 4.2 I guess? You'd have to rewrite it. Badly done (because it doesn't stop at first encounter, it could be `currentResult.filter({ $0.name == current.name }).first`

Comment: Nope. I use 4.1. Now I'm getting "Cannot subscript a value of type '[Sales]' with an index of type 'Sales'" in let existingSale  = currentResult[existingSalesIndex]

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use Swift 4.2? Else you'd have to rewrite `index(where:)`. Something like `let existingIndex = NSNotFound; for anIndex, aSale in currentResults { if aSale.name == current.name { index = anIndex; break } } if existingIndex != NSNotFound { currentResult.append(current) } else { let existingSale = currentResult[existingSalesIndex]; currentResult[existingSalesIndex] = Sales(withSales: existingSale, otherSale: current)}

Comment: Nice use of reduce(), but using `firstIndex(where:)` on an array has `O(n)` performance, so doing that on every element has `O(n²)` performance. On moderate-sized arrays that's going to be slow, and on large arrays it will be **SSSSSLLLLLOOOOOOWWWWW**. It would be better to reduce the results into a set or a dictionary, then map the set back into an array at the end. (Sets and dictionaries have ≈constant time complexity for searching, making the whole process ≈`O(n)`.

Comment: @Larme - I just didn't upgrade my xcode. Will upgrade and try

Comment: @DuncanC - Can you please show me some example code?

Comment: If I get a chance I'll rewrite it using a dictionary or an array. If you're working with arrays of <50 items don't worry about it, but as the array size grows the time needed is going to grow dramatically.

Comment: See Martin R's answer. He maps the output to a Dictionary, which should be fast. Same with Daniyal Raza's answer.

Comment: Thank you all. It was very interesting. I marked Martin's solution as the answer. The solution provided by Larme, Duncan, Daniyal Raza, Duncan could also work. Since I'm in the tight schedule, I didn't try the solution. Once again, thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Sale Class:

```
class Sale{
        var soldBy:String
        var amount:Double

        init(soldBy:String, amount:Double) {
            self.soldBy = soldBy
            self.amount = amount
        }
}
```

Calculate output:

```
let output = sales.reduce([String:Double]()) { (result, sale) -> [String:Double] in
        var result = result
        result[sale.soldBy, default: 0.0] += sale.amount
        return result
}
```

**Reference :** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2925471-reduce

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init):

```
let groupedSales: [Sale] = Dictionary(grouping: sales) { $0.soldBy }
    .lazy
    .map { element in
        let sum = element.value.lazy.map { $0.saleAmount }.reduce(0,+)
        //Or as suggested by Mr Martin: let sum = element.value.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.saleAmount })
        return Sale(soldBy: element.key, saleAmount: sum)
    }
```

And now you can print the result:

```
for s in groupedSales {
    print(s.soldBy, s.saleAmount)
}
//ABC 5699.67
//DEF 1111.44
```

I've added this initializer to the `Sale` class for convenience:

```
class Sale  {
    var soldBy : String = ""
    var saleAmount : Double = 0.00

    init(soldBy: String, saleAmount: Double) {
        self.soldBy = soldBy
        self.saleAmount = saleAmount
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `element.value.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.saleAmount })` instead of lazy and map.

Comment: @MartinR I like it 

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @DaniyalRaza's answer, and doing some cleanup:

```
class Sale: CustomStringConvertible {
    var soldBy:String
    var amount:Double

    init(soldBy:String, amount:Double) {
        self.soldBy = soldBy
        self.amount = amount
    }

    //This lets us use string interpolation to display a `Sale` object
    var description: String {
        return "Sale(soldBy:\"\(soldBy)\",amount:\(amount)"
    }
}

let sales: [Sale] = [Sale(soldBy: "ABC", amount: 1200.34),
                      Sale(soldBy: "ABC", amount: 999.34),
                      Sale(soldBy: "ABC", amount: 3499.99),
                      Sale(soldBy: "DEF", amount: 333.32),
                      Sale(soldBy: "DEF", amount: 778.12)]


let output: [Sale] = sales.reduce([String:Double]()) { (result, sale) -> [String:Double] in
    var result = result
    result[sale.soldBy, default: 0.0] += sale.amount
    return result
}
    //Map the dictionary from the above back to an array
    .map { Sale(soldBy: $0.key, amount: $0.value) }

    //Sort the output back into alphabetical order by soldBy (if desired)
    //Note that sorting will take time, so only do this step if needed.
    .sorted { $0.soldBy < $1.soldBy }

print(output)
```

Comment: Maybe use reduce(into:) to avoid creating a mutable copy each time?